# Can structural changes in sublist reflected in the original list, in JAVA?

Tags: java

In the document of List class:

```
/*
The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. 
*/
    List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex);
```

Can structural changes in sublist reflected in the original list in JAVA?
I have do an experiment and it told me the answer is "can", but I am not sure.
My experiment code is below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Student> a=new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(new Student("Lily",16));
        a.add(new Student("Sam",16));
        a.add(new Student("Tom",16));
        a.add(new Student("Mary",16));
        a.add(new Student("Mark",16));
        a.add(new Student("John",16));

        List<Student> suba=a.subList(2,5);

        System.out.println("Firstly,suba:");
        printall(suba);
        
        System.out.println("Change the structure:");
        suba.remove(0);
        System.out.println("suba:");
        printall(suba);
        System.out.println("a:");
        printall(a);
    }
    public static void printall(List<Student> list){
        for (Student a : list){
            System.out.print(a+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
class Student{
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public Student(String name,int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }

    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name :"+this.name+"age :"+this.age;
    }
}
```

and the result is:

```
Firstly,suba:
name :Tomage :16    name :Maryage :16   name :Markage :16   
Change the structure:
suba:
name :Maryage :16   name :Markage :16   
a:
name :Lilyage :16   name :Samage :16    name :Maryage :16   name :Markage :16   name :Johnage :16
```

The node Tom is deleted, the structure of the ArrayList has changed.Does my assumption true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `subList` returns a "view" of your original list. Any method accessing the list through the sub list effectively does `index + offset`.

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) continues to state (emphasis mine):

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become *undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list*. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

What that means is that if you remove or add elements from the original list, accessing the sub list *might* throw an exception, because you are accessing items outside of the list. Or you might access different elements than you expect, because elements in the original list have shifted (and the sub list is only adding the offset for every index operation).

In other words: with current implementations, some structural modifications of the original list are reflected in the sublist, but there is no guarantee that they are. There are no guarantees either that your sub list will continue to work. Maybe it does, maybe it does not. Maybe it is going to an exception, or maybe it is not. Maybe it is throwing an exception later or accessing the wrong elements. Maybe it isn't. TLDR: Don't rely on *undefined behavior*.

Please note that there are other list implementations apart from `ArrayList`, e.g. `LinkedList`, which might behave differently when sublisted (there are at least two sublist implementations: `RandomAccessSubList` and `SubList`).

You can find the source of the sub list wrapper(s) in the OpenJDK source code: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/default/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java